# How to shift a histogram to the right?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter, histogram

I have a 1D array for a histogram with bin boundaries:

```
bins = np.arange(1, 6,2)
data = np.array([1,2,3,4,4,4,3,2,3,3,3])
plt.hist(data, bins=bins, histtype='step')
```

But I want to shift thee histogram horizontally to the right by 1 unit on the x-axis, how do I do that? I don't want the shape of bin boundaries to change but just the whole histogram to shift.

I tried doing:

```
x0 = 1
plt.hist(data+x0, bins=np.arange(1+x0, 6+x0,2+x0), histtype='step')
```

but it changes the bin boundaries. How do I ammend this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but in your `np.arange` you don't want to increase the step size.  So:

```
plt.hist(data+x0, bins=np.arange(1+x0, 6+x0, 2), histtype='step')
```

Both graphs:

[image]